# bxslider hover effect on li

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I am using bxSlider to have a carousel [on my page](http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-dynamic-number-slides), I want to show a hidden div when the user hover any `li` tag. When I finally did it I noticed that there's is a problem when I do the hovering, the div appear and then disappear by itself in matter of seconds.

[Here's my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YN2Wc/) and this is my jquery to show the div

```
$("#li1").hover(
    function () {
        $("#1").fadeIn();
    },
    function () {
        $("#1").fadeOut();
    }
);
```

Comment: it's because when the `#1` fades in, it covers the `#li1` so it unhovers and fades out again

Comment: ohh...so what it is your suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#li1` was triggering a `mouseleave` once the hidden layer was overlapping it.
The `#1` was renamed as `#hidden1` since it is not a valid ID token and querying for it will fail in several browsers;

This should work:

```
$("#li1").mouseenter(function () {
    $("#hidden1").fadeIn();
})

$("#hidden1").mouseleave(function () {
    $("#hidden1").fadeOut()
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YN2Wc/2/

Your hidden div is not overlapping completely the visible trigger. This will cause this toggle to flicker.

Comment: your jsfiddle works great, but in my site something is wrong because now i hover the li and dont get to see anything, ill have to check it but thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Here's a more complete file http://jsfiddle.net/mVLbm/2/ btw I am using bootstrap and bxSlider plug in probably that doesnt have to do with the error that i am having since the jsfiddles work fine but just saying, thanks again i really appreciate your help and time.

Comment: In your fiddle if you hover #li1 the hidden element shows. What seems to be the problem?